# JSSOR - Cannot read type property 'currentStyle' of undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined, jssor

I'm trying to implement the Jssor slider into my page, but I keep coming up with that error in the title.

My content is being dynamically created via Javascript, like so:

```
var slide = app.createHTML('div', "", {'id':'inventorySlides'}, null);

var div = document.getElementById('invDiv');
div.appendChild(slide);
```

and then I procedurally generate cell divs in the same way and append them to `slide`.

I've defined a function in my main controller as in the example on the basic usage page (http://www.jssor.com/development/basic-usage-no-jquery.html), and after all the content has been generated and appended, I call the function

```
jssor_slider1_starter('inventorySlides');
```

But then I get the error message in the console. I've tried logging the inventorySlides div, and it definitely exists in the DOM, so I know it's not that. I tried searching for `currentStyles`, which turns out is just on IE and Opera, and I'm using Chrome.

So is it something I'm doing wrong? Or is it Jssor that's misbehaving?

Comment: `currentStyle` is an old IE version (IE8) of `getComputedStyle`, and it seems the plugin is faulty and fails to indentify your browser.

Comment: turns out I forgot to include jssor.core.js and jssor.utils.js (they should really put that in bold, and the example only shows jssor.slider.min.js being included). However, I'm still getting the error

Comment: figured it out: I needed to create a div with an attribute `u="slides`, which does inside the 'inventorySlides' div, and the cells are nested inside this new div....

Comment: Thanks for updating solution @DanTheGameMan

Comment: Thanks, just saved me heaps of time :)

Comment: Yup, sorry about that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So firstly, I had forgotten to include jssor.core.js and jssor.utils.js, though that did not fully solve my problem.

The Solution was that I needed to create a div with an attribute `u="slides"`, which goes inside the 'inventorySlides' div, and the cells are nested inside this new div

NOTE: I made this answer much later than when it was asked because at the time I did not have enough reputation to be able to answer my own question, and now I no longer have access to the code this question is referencing, so I can't really add much more detail to the answer than what had already been discussed in the comments. I apologize if there's any details you need that this answer does not provide, but I can't help much past this point. Cheers - Dan

Answer (score 0):

If you are including jssor.js file after the html slider elements, then you are getting same error.

The solution : include jssor.js file bottom of the page.